# How to call generic Method in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I am writing custom C# class library for exception handling.

```
public static void HandleErrorMessage(string eventId,string libraryName)
{
    try
    {
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Now I have to write one more method for below scenario. There are couple of chances other developers want to customize their exceptions, for example: they don't want to send the error object to this exception library. It should be able to pick those things up.
I am not able to get how to accept different classes to a single method, seems generics may be useful. Can anybody provide syntax for how to call the method for this scenario?
It should be some thing like this, but not getting how to call this method:

```
public static void HandleCustomExceptions<T>(ref T customizedexceptionMessage, 
                                             ref T Actualerror)
{           
}
```

Comment: Generics are useful when you want to accept different classes that are all treated *the same way*. Are you sure that is what you are aiming for?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: my method has to accept all the classes if they are getting exception , then my method has to receive class name,and if any value they pass. once i received those messages i have to send to service bus. at this point of time i am thinking,  need to provice a template to pass thier class name and method name where they are getting the error. I am looking for that template only. thanks in advance

Comment: How do you currently wire the exceptions to this method?

Comment: @Stefan: for system exceptions: normal try catch i am using :              public static void HandleErrorMessage(string eventId,string libraryName , string uName,string messageString,string obj)  I am facing issue for if other developers send some custom exceptions have to send to some other queue.

Comment: Why is customized exception message of type `T`. Why isn't it a string? Let other developers format the string in whichever way they want?

Comment: @Yuval: some times they may send the error codes , which will accepted by service bus. even your answer is some what convincing to me. could you provide any syntax if i write this method, how to test. HandleCustomExceptions<ClassName>("Error Message", "ActualError");

Comment: Why not have a method signature like `public void HandleCustomExceptions(string errorMessage, Exception exception)`? Why do you need the class name when you have the stacktrace?

Comment: @Yuval: there is a need to create 3 methods for the scenarios.
1) if there is a system exception, the first would be called
2)if there is a validation error such as email format not matching, etc, the second method would be called

3)and if there is a case where an erroneous object needs to be passed, the third would be called 
The first 2 would be possible from your suggestion, but third one developers will pass their own exception message , for that scenario need to get the error object and based on that it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply substitute 'T' with Type of Object you want to use.However the above statement needs the enclosing class to be declared as type of T as

```
public class Handler<T>:where T:Exception{ //or expect the T to be only the child or implemented class of T to strongly type
public static void HandleCustomExceptions<T>(ref T customizedexceptionMessage, 
                                         ref T Actualerror)
 {
    try
    {
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
 }
}
```

use class it as

```
Handler<ArgumentNullException> handler=new Handler<ArgumentNullException>();
Exception ex=new ArgumentNullException();
handler.HandleCustomExceptions(ref ex,ref anotherexception);
```

note that 'WHERE' clause, you will not be able to use the class with any types as

```
Handler<string> handler =new ...//won't work as T is expected to be either Exception or class that inherit Excpetion class .on lower note Exception can be substituted as Interface i.e. like IException
```

Generics are useful if you want the code to be shared across same hierarchy of Objects as in here Exception or in most common; Repository as in EF.

Generics introduce to the .NET Framework the concept of type parameters, which make it possible to design classes and methods that defer the specification of one or more types until the class or method is declared and instantiated by client code. For example, by using a generic type parameter T you can write a single class that other client code can use without incurring the cost or risk of runtime casts or boxing operations.Taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

you are not restricted to use only one Generic Types you can add more as in previous class you can have Method as

```
public void WriteLog<TLogger>(TLogger logger,T exception):where T:ILogger //your Logger Implementation
{ //note you have already defined T as Excpetion in class constraint
 ...
}
```